# Fetch Azure devops PipelineJobs data in Power BI

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, azure-pipelines, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to get PipelineJobOutcome values from Azure devops to PowerBI

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could use the following query in Power BI to check if it meet your requirements:

```
let
   Source = OData.Feed ("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/PipelineRuns?"
        &"$apply=filter( "
                &"PipelineId eq {pipelineId} "
                &"and CompletedDate ge {startdate} "
                &") "
        &"/aggregate( "
        &"$count as TotalCount, "
            &"SucceededCount with sum as SucceededCount , "
                &"FailedCount with sum as FailedCount, "
                &"PartiallySucceededCount with sum as PartiallySucceededCount , "
            &"CanceledCount with sum as CanceledCount "
                &") "
    ,null, [Implementation="2.0",OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataVersion = 4]) 
in
    Source
```

For more information, you could refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-pipelines-outcome-summary?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi).

Comment: I am aware of this.
But, this is not the desired output.